# Google Access tokens invalid with php client

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I am developing a site accessible only from a company VPN that utilizes google sign in, which is working. I am adding the ability to import data from Google Sheets. I have added the required scopes to the sign in:

```
function renderButton()
{
    gapi.signin2.render('sign_in', {
        'scope': 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
        'width': 120,
        'height': 36,
        'longtitle': false,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSignIn,
        //'onfailure': onFailure
    });
}
```

OnSignIn stores the token as a cookie:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;


    setCookie("Google_ID", profile.getId());
    setCookie('Full_Name', profile.getName());
    setCookie('Given_Name', profile.getGivenName());
    setCookie('Family_Name', profile.getFamilyName());
    setCookie("Image_URL", profile.getImageUrl());
    setCookie("Email", profile.getEmail()); 
    setCookie("ID_Token", id_token);

    doLogin();
}
```

In doLogin() I call the php script that executes the php client (as well as other unrelated tasks not included):

```
$.post(API, {action:'test_google_client'},
function(data, status)
{
    console.log("Google result: " + data);
});
```

Which calls this php function that uses google php APIs:

```
function Test_Google_Client($dbh)
{
    $token = $_COOKIE["ID_Token"];

    print('Token Valid: ' . testGoogleToken($token) . '|||');
    print('Token: ' . $token . '|||');

    $client = getGoogleClient($token);

    print('Created Client |||');

    $sheets = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    print('Created Spreadsheet |||');

    $spreadsheetId = '<spreadsheet id>';
    $range = 'A2:M';
    $rows = $sheets->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range, ['majorDimension' => 'ROWS']);

    pre($rows);
}

function getGoogleClient($token)
{
    $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => Get_Client_ID(), 'client_secret' => Get_Client_Secrete()]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
    //$client->setAccessType('offline');

    return $client;
}

function testGoogleToken($token)
{
    $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => Get_Client_ID()]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($token);

    //pre($client);

    return $payload;
}
```

The result printed from this function is:

> Google result: Token Valid: |||Token: *valid access token
>   omitted*|||Created Client |||Created Spreadsheet |||
>  **Fatal
>   error**:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {   "error":
>   {
>       "code": 401,
>       "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other
>   valid authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.&quot;,
>       "errors": [
>         {
>           "message": "Invalid Credentials",
>           "domain": "global",
>           "reason": "authError",
>           "location": "Authorization",
>           "locationType": "header"
>         }
>       ],
>       "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"   } }  in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Development\php\google\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118
>   Stack trace:
>   0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Development\php\google\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
>   1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Development\php\google\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176):
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
>   2 C: in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Development\php\google\src\Google\Http\REST.php**
>   on line **118**

So essentially, verifyIdToken is returning empty, implying the token is not valid, and the spreadsheet is giving an error saying it isn't valid. What am I missing to properly verify and use ID tokens?

EDIT: after reviewing more instructions on https://theonetechnologies.com/blog/post/how-to-get-google-app-client-id-and-client-secret for setting credentials, I have gotten verifyIdToken() to return the correct value. I have also added the required libraries on developer console and have added the necessary scopes for the consent screen in console. The call to gsheets is still returning the same error.

Comment: I think that only oauth2 is accepted now. Not sure